# Apple rejected my app saying "We were unable to review your app, as it crashed on launch"

Tags: ios, app-store, swift2

Apple rejected my app saying:

> 1.2.0 Binary Rejected
>
> 2.1 Details: We were unable to review your app, as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this
>
> 2.1 Details:
> We were unable to review your app, as it crashed on launch. We have
> attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

I had already tested my app and I was able to use and test my app before submitting it for review.
It did not crash on launch.

Following is the crash log provided by apple:

```
Incident Identifier: 9E5C39A4-8777-4BD1-94E9-2EE850653055
CrashReporter Key:   93dafa1433ee75ef4dc2d9ecf04d1e297fbba0d5
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             AppName [664]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/174AD849-AE8A-4A0C-8747-F03CE08640DB/AppName.app/AppName
Identifier:          com.app.appname.AppName
Version:             1 (1.2.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-10-25 11:43:08.08 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-10-25 11:43:03.03 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 9.1 (13B143)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x185910f48 0x19a757f80 0x185910e18 0x186804a1c 0x18b14c414 0x18b148f50 0x18f5877c4 0x18f587b44 0x1858c8544 0x1858c7fd8 0x1858c5cd8 0x1857f4ca0 0x18af121c8 0x18af0cffc 0x1001fd6c4 0x19afa68b8)

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
5.115077     CFNetwork                  0x0000000185011a18 TCP Conn 0x13ce7fb40 SSL Handshake DONE
5.135314     CFNetwork                  0x0000000185011928 TCP Conn 0x13ce7fb40 starting SSL negotiation
5.135787     CFNetwork                  0x00000001850b3a30 TCP Conn 0x13ce7fb40 complete. fd: 12, err: 0
5.136040     CFNetwork                  0x00000001850b4f5c TCP Conn 0x13ce7fb40 event 1. err: 0
5.148872     CFNetwork                  0x00000001850b5034 TCP Conn 0x13ce7fb40 started
5.150566     CFNetwork                  0x000000018510a608 Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
5.150566     CFNetwork                  0x000000018510a5d4 Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
5.150566     CFNetwork                  0x000000018515c394 Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b0c3140 0x19b0a8000 + 110912
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b18cef8 0x19b188000 + 20216
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019b036b78 0x19afd4000 + 404344
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000199dcd3f4 0x199dcc000 + 5108
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000199de9e98 0x199dcc000 + 122520
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019a758248 0x19a750000 + 33352
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000199de6f44 0x199dcc000 + 110404
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000199de6b10 0x199dcc000 + 109328
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019a758120 0x19a750000 + 33056
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001857f4d48 0x1857ec000 + 36168
10  UIKit                           0x000000018af121c8 0x18ae8c000 + 549320
11  UIKit                           0x000000018af0cffc 0x18ae8c000 + 528380
12  AppName                         0x00000001001fd6c4 0x100064000 + 1676996
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019afa68b8 0x19afa4000 + 10424

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b0c3b6c 0x19b0a8000 + 113516
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b189530 0x19b188000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b189020 0x19b188000 + 4128

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b0c44fc 0x19b0a8000 + 115964
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019af88a04 0x19af74000 + 84484
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019af77874 0x19af74000 + 14452

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b0c3b6c 0x19b0a8000 + 113516
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b189530 0x19b188000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b189020 0x19b188000 + 4128

Thread 4 name:  GAIThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b0a8a40 0x19b0a8000 + 2624
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b0a88bc 0x19b0a8000 + 2236
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001858c8108 0x1857ec000 + 901384
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001858c5e0c 0x1857ec000 + 892428
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001857f4ca0 0x1857ec000 + 36000
5   Foundation                      0x000000018676d2bc 0x186760000 + 53948
6   Foundation                      0x00000001867c28f4 0x186760000 + 403700
7   AppName                         0x00000001002472d0 0x100064000 + 1979088
8   Foundation                      0x0000000186853c80 0x186760000 + 998528
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b18bb28 0x19b188000 + 15144
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b18ba8c 0x19b188000 + 14988
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b189028 0x19b188000 + 4136

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b0c3b6c 0x19b0a8000 + 113516
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b189530 0x19b188000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b189020 0x19b188000 + 4128

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b0a8a40 0x19b0a8000 + 2624
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b0a88bc 0x19b0a8000 + 2236
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001858c8108 0x1857ec000 + 901384
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001858c5e0c 0x1857ec000 + 892428
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001857f4ca0 0x1857ec000 + 36000
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018508db84 0x184fe0000 + 711556
6   Foundation                      0x0000000186853c80 0x186760000 + 998528
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b18bb28 0x19b188000 + 15144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b18ba8c 0x19b188000 + 14988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b189028 0x19b188000 + 4136

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b0c3368 0x19b0a8000 + 111464
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001858ce670 0x1857ec000 + 927344
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b18bb28 0x19b188000 + 15144
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b18ba8c 0x19b188000 + 14988
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b189028 0x19b188000 + 4136

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000013ce0a0b7
    x4: 0x0000000199deae02   x5: 0x000000016fd9b520   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000f80
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000002  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000030000000300
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001a1986000  x21: 0x000000016fd9b520  x22: 0x000000013cd28c50  x23: 0x00000001a1991b68
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0xb400b434638f59a0  x26: 0x000000013ce00a50  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000001  fp: 0x000000016fd9b480   lr: 0x000000019b18cef8
    sp: 0x000000016fd9b460   pc: 0x000000019b0c3140 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x100064000 - 0x100693fff AppName arm64  <4ec6d754547d35e0ac7cdec73135e3f7> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/174AD849-AE8A-4A0C-8747-F03CE08640DB/AppName.app/AppName
0x100874000 - 0x1008cbfff Alamofire arm64  <5108ad4090ed34eb91c922f2403e5d44> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/174AD849-AE8A-4A0C-8747-F03CE08640DB/AppName.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
0x100ad0000 - 0x100ad7fff libswiftAVFoundation.dylib arm64  <8f4c4419e8c33db7a3c122d8fc56cc09> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/174AD849-AE8A-4A0C-8747-F03CE08640DB/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
0x100af4000 - 0x100d07fff libswiftCore.dylib arm64  <1c8fc0a4195f3207ac97389aafa69c65> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/174AD849-AE8A-4A0C-8747-F03CE08640DB/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
```

How do I see the exact error/reason for crash?
What should I do now?

Comment: I don't see any mention of a specific error, but this line seems relevant `12  AppName 0x00000001001fd6c4 0x100064000 + 1676996`. Maybe someone with more experience can comment.

Comment: How did you test before submission? What device? What OS?

Comment: You should symbolicate the crash to see which line of your code crashes. Also you should test you app against all devices/os

Comment: Hi I am also suffer this can u get any solution for this.